# Poisson Distribution, not sure how to include several events

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This is the very last question on an assignment sheet and for some reason I can't wrap my head around the very last sentence without doubting my approach. Here's the question:

> Tony’s home has a number of electric lights, which fail from time to
>   time and have to be replaced. On average Tony has to replace 1.5 light
>   bulbs every month.
>
> (i) What is the appropriate distribution of the total number of light
>   bulbs which need to be replaced each year? What are its mean and
>   variance?
>
> (ii) What is the probability that Tony will have to replace at least
>   one light bulb in each of the next three months?

For (i) I've said that I think it's Poisson Distribution and both the mean and variance will be 18 for a full year.

For (ii) I've written down the following:

Let $ \lambda$ be $1.5$, $P(X \ge 1) = 1 - P(X = 0)$

$$ P(X = 0) = {e^{1.5} \cdot 1.5^0 \over 0!}$$

$$= 1 - 0.3347\ldots$$

I'm not even sure if that's on the right track, but it occured to me that I have to somehow account for the last part:

> in each of the next three months.

Comment: Yes, thanks - I've been up all night watching Harvard lectures to try get ahead with my coursework so my brain is a bit fried.

Comment: By the way, the numerical calculation of $\Pr(X=0)$ is not correct. This probability is $e^{-1.5}\approx 0.22313$. It looks as if you multiplied by $(1.5)^1$, not by $(1.5)^0$, which is $1$.

Comment: Yeah you're right, silly mistake. But right now I'm really confused about when to use $1 - ...$. Because I see $Pr(X = x)$ and $Pr(X > x)$ and $Pr(X < x)$. When should I use which?

Comment: The poisson takes on only non-negative integer values. Use $\Pr(X\gt x)$ is the wording is something like "is greater than $x$." Usually the English wording will be quite precise. If you want the probability that $X$ is at least $2$, that means $2$ or more, so $\gt 1$. Easier to get at as $1-(\Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=1))$.

Comment: But what if it says something like X is at least 600? Is there a general solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are invited to assume that the lifetimes of bulbs have exponential distribution, which is a somewhat unreasonable assumption. But never mind, we will hold our noses and think Poisson.

The number of failures in a month has Poisson distribution, mean $1.5$.

We have $3$ independent Poisson random variables, $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$, which give us the number of failures in the first month, the second, the third.

We want the probability that $X_1\gt 0$ **and** $X_2\gt 0$ **and** $X_3\gt 0$.

Note that $\Pr(X_i\gt 0)=1-e^{-1.5}$.

Comment: Does the 'and' imply that I should multiply them together as they are independent?

Comment: Yes. That's why the "and" was in boldface, so that it would remind you of what you know.

Comment: One more thing, you mentioned that $\Pr(X_i\gt 0)=1-e^{-1.5}$, but isn't that for P ~ Expo?, ie the CDF

Comment: The probability for the Poisson is the same (and for good reason). For the Poisson, the formula you are familiar with says $e^{-1.5}\frac{(1.5)^0}{0!}$. But $0!=1$ and $(1.5)^0=1$.